# How Do I Blur The Black Box / Border In This Super Simple Example?

Tags: html, css

All I am trying to do is replace the black box with a box that will blur the background image. This is an over simplified version of my webpage. If I can just get this code corrected, I can figure out the rest.

Here's my example and code:
https://jsfiddle.net/no_u_turn/8ymc7xeb/1/

```css
body {
  background-image:url('https://i.ibb.co/DKtSK1h/background-image.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.top-box {
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:100px;
}

.blur-background-box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:black;
  /*filter:blur(5px);*/
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top:50px;
}

.solid-white-box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:white;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.bottom-box {
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
    <div class="blur-background-box">
        <div class="solid-white-box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-box">
</div>
```

Oh yeah, I need this done in CSS only, no JavaScript. Basically, I need the code to work with all browsers and across all devices.

I'll be working on this all night. Any and all suggestions are welcome! Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using `background-attachment:fixed;` you can then apply the same background on the black box and you will have the needed effect. To avoid having the content blurred use a pseudo element:

```css
body {
  background-image:url('https://i.ibb.co/DKtSK1h/background-image.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

.top-box {
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:100px;
}

.blur-background-box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top:50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.blur-background-box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-image:url('https://i.ibb.co/DKtSK1h/background-image.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  filter:blur(5px);
}

.solid-white-box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:white;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.bottom-box {
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
    <div class="blur-background-box">
        <div class="solid-white-box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-box">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, you are a genius! I will try my hardest to study this code so I can understand it. If I have any problems with it not working on certain browsers I will post back here. Thx again Temani Afif!

Comment: Update: Well, I implemented your code into my website template, and it works flawless on all desktop browsers with the exceptions of IE (old) and Edge. There is flickering and no blur on both. I also tested on my Android phone using Chrome and it too does not look proper. I am paying for traffic to my site, so I need the code to be flawless on all devices.

Comment: I think the problem might be with this line of code: .blur-background-box:before     Is there another way I can accomplish this goal using different code? If you don't want to do the coding for me (again) can you please point me in the right direction to perhaps some  similar examples?

Comment: Thx again for your time! I really appreciate it! I spent maybe 9 hours working on this the other day with no luck. Getting HTML to look proper on all devices and browsers has always been the main challenge for us web developers.

Comment: @No-U-Turn I will try to see what I can do with it ;)

Comment: @No-U-Turn I think you won't have a chance with IE and edge. IE don't support the filter. With edge it seems there is a bug when using negative z-index. I have updated so that it can work on edge